# Avoid form fields resetting when going back after following a link

Tags: forms, reset

I'd like to make sure that after *editing* and then *navigating away* from a form (pressing Back or clicking a link) and *returning* (using the Back or Forward button), the form data is **not reset**. I have verified that this works on another web site. What do I need to check?

Before answering, please note that I'm **not submitting** and then going back. Simply following links and then returning.

Context:

- **Firefox**.
- **JavaScript is disabled** in the browser.
- The web site is on an **intranet**.
- A **proxy** is used system-wide, but it connects directly on the intranet.
- The web page is served over **HTTP**.
- The markup is **valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional**.
- The markup contains **no frames**.
- The back-end language is **PHP**.
- The web server is **Apache**.
- The server is a custom **Linux** distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers cache form input values. So when user refreshes page, the inputs have same values.

You should check your code-behind for browser cache manipulations like:

```
<?
  Header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  Header('Pragma: no-cache');
  ?>
```

and also your plain HTML-templates for:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 2000 12:12:12 GMT">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: Will do. I'll get back to you with the results.